# Basic Column Chart Example Does Not Load On Page - Error Returned

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have a column chart replicated to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt6b4/1/). On the js fiddle the chart does not load. However on my page the error `Cannot read property 'bp' of undefined` appears on my web page (not on the console). Below is my code.

HTML

```
<head>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart"></div> 
  <script>
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });

    google.setOnLoadCallback(

    function drawChart() {
        var data  =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Name',  'Numbers'],
            ['All',   67000],
            ['Paid to Date',   40000]
        ]);

        // Create and draw the visualization.
        new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart')).draw(
        data, {
            width: 350,
             height: 200,
            hAxis:   { baselineColor:  'white' 
            },
            vAxis:   { baselineColor:  'white',
                gridlines:   { color:  'black',
                     count:  2
                },
                ticks:   [0,  90000]
            },
            legend:   { position:  "none" 
            }
        });
    })
  </script>  
</body>
```

I'm hoping that figuring out what's wrong with the js fiddle and applying that fix to my app will fix the issue. So the question becomes, what's wrong with the code? Why is this error popping up on the page where my column chart should be?

Comment: To make the Visualization API work on jsfiddle, you have to change the default "onLoad" option under "Frameworks and Extensions" to either of the "No Wrap" options.  You also should only call `google.load` once, though the second call is probably not causing your problems.  Here's an updated fiddle that works: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/xt6b4/2/

Comment: Thanks for the fix on fiddle. Unfortunately I'm unable to replicate this onto my app. I'm still receiving the error `Cannot read property 'ed' of undefined`. A slightly different error from the previous one before.

Comment: Are you using any javascript libraries or frameworks that may be messing with object prototypes?  Do you have any errors showing up in the developer's console in Chrome or Firefox?

Comment: I don't think so. I have jquery and angular. No errors that affect object prototypes exist in the console.

Comment: Are there errors in the console (whether they affect object prototypes or not)?  Is the page public-facing, so I can test it myself?

Comment: The only error I have is this `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=rl3dkm&userId=gbasdFweD32qyEeqeE12yew6&CTID=AutoTranslate". `

Comment: Can you update your question with your full HTML/javascript so I can test this?

Comment: I updated my question with the relevant code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55881/discussion-between-asgallant-and-jason328).